# QtCreator без Qt

Tags: c++, qtcreator, static, c++17

Решил я поэкспериментировать c GUI либой - [Nana](http://nanapro.org/en-us/). Но не думал, что столько заморочек с ней будет. Очень непонятно, почему "штатный" MinGW32 7.3.0, входящий в последнюю поставку Qt не захотел компилировать либу. Ну я подумал, они там все на "пике стандартов" ... поставил MSYS, в который вошел GCC уже версии 10.1.0 - либа таки собралась.

Но потом встал вопрос компиляции тестового примера. Всеми правдами и неправдами я убил тучу времени на поиски и таки нашаманил работающий пакетный файл для сборки:

```
@echo off
SET PATH=C:\Tools\Msys64\mingw64\bin;%PATH%

C:\Tools\Msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe ^
 -IC:\Projects\c++\Nana\mingw-x64\include ^
 -LC:\Projects\c++\Nana\mingw-x64\lib ^
 -std=c++17 ^
 main.cpp -O3 -o NanaTest.exe ^
 -lnana -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lz -Wl,-subsystem,windows ^
 -static -lpthread

strip NanaTest.exe
```

А вот теперь вопрос - как все это раскидать по настройкам в .pro файл для QtCreator'а?

Нужные профили комплектов MSYS в QtCreator'е создал.

Comment: Типичный пример того, как IDE себе слишком многое позволяют... Ну а сдесь все решается просто: зачем вы используете qmake? qmake - кусок г*****а и это даже не мое оценочное суждение, это говорят и те, кто его создал! Не задумывались зачем им две системы сборки? qbs должна была заменить qmake но оказалась не лучше его. Используйте cmake - qtcreator его поддерживает, сами qt-шники планируют на него перейти

Comment: Что же касается поддержки 17-ого стандарта, то gcc его поддерживает только начиная с 8 версии.

Comment: Блин, сбили с толку "нанайцы" ... Они-то у себя заявляют про свою либу как "`LANGUAGE C++11/14/17`, `COMPILER Any Standard C++ compiler(Visual C++ 2013, GCC/MinGW and Clang)`". А по факту - пилят на с++17.

Comment: на счет `cmake` vs `qbs` - у меня опыта особого не было, но `qbs`- показалась более структурированной. Чем она плоха и чем лучше cmake?

Comment: чем плох qbs? Ну например тем, что его поддержкой занимается один человек, он не смог вытеснить даже qmake (для чего он и писался), я даже не знаю ни одного проекта (прилаги, либы и т.д.) которая его бы использовала, отсутствие сообщества. То что qbs более структурирован - да, странно было бы ожидать другого, учитывая что его писали на замену, учитывая проблемы первой системы. Чем лучше cmake? Во-первых это целый язык программирования (очень компактный), прекрасная человеко читаемость, большое сообщество и огромное количество проектов написанных с его помощью.

Comment: Ну ок ... Если не заленюсь, попробую все же добить свой этот вопрос на трех системах сборки. Чисто для расширения кругозора. А за инфу - конечно спасибо. Хотя это и не "полноценный" ответ, но мысли - правильные! Щя "приподыму" тебе комменты)

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch , и еще ... когда один человек занимается - это не всегда плохой показатель. Во времена засилия DOS была такая утилита "keyrus" - шикарная до безобразия! Так вот, сперва умер ее автор, а она продолжала жить вплоть до появления Win95. Она у меня, если память не изменяет, еще на OS/2 3.61 в DOS-боксах бегала. Вывод - ручки решают, если умения их не хватает - решает количество. ИМХО.

Comment: Ну, поддержкой QBS сейчас занимается сообщество, я знаю как минимум 6-х разработчиков (что достаточно). А насчет того, что CMake - это целый язык программирования и у него хорошая человекочитаемость - так это бред, ИМХО. И насчет того, что QBS хуже чем qmake - еще один бред, т.к. оно даже лучше чем CMake.

Comment: qbs - на сколько я осведомлен, имеет описание в стиле JSON, а это уже стопицот очков в пользу наглядности. ИМХО.

Comment: Да, с наглядностью в QBS все хорошо. Другой плюс - это то что не нужно устанавливать всяких дополнительных утилит для сборки (типа Make, Ninja, Python и прочее), т.к. QBS собирает все сам. Кроме того, QBS очень гибкий и простой, разберется даже малышок )), здесь нет такого количества противоречивой документации и информации - все описывается лаконично и читабельно.

Comment: UPD: Лично Я, к примеру, всегда предпочитаю использовать QBS как в своих DIY проектах (для микроконтроллеров), так и в проектах на работе (как для МК, так и для десктопа) в связке с QtCreator, если нет никаких требований у заказчика и прочее. Но, сколько людей - столько и предпочтений... тут главное попробовать то и сё, а потом выбрать что ближе по духу. ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, в QBS (для MinGW) твой проект будет примерно таким:

```
import qbs

CppApplication {
    name: "NanaTest"

    cpp.distributionIncludePaths: ["C:/Projects/c++/Nana/mingw-x64/include"]
    cpp.distributionLibraryPaths: ["C:/Projects/c++/Nana/mingw-x64/lib"]
    cpp.cxxLanguageVersion: "c++17"
    cpp.optimization: "fast"
    cpp.dynamicLibraries: ["nana", "gdi32", "comdlg32", "z", "pthread"]
    cpp.linkerFlags: ["-subsystem", "windows"]
    cpp.cxxFlags: ["-static"]

    files: ["main.cpp"]
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вполне себе! Еще просьба, если не трудно - покажите как добавить альтернативу, чтобы QBS определял текущую выбранную битность проекта. И использовал например `C:/Projects/c++/Nana/mingw-x32/include`, и `C:/Projects/c++/Nana/mingw-x32/lib` если выбрана x32

Answer (score 1):

Сделать как-то так:

```
...
    Properties {
        condition: qbs.architecture === "x86"
        cpp.distributionIncludePaths: ["C:/path/to/32/bit/include"]
        cpp.distributionLibraryPaths: ["C:/path/to/32/bit/lib"]
    }
...
    Properties {
        condition: qbs.architecture === "x86_64"
        cpp.distributionIncludePaths: ["C:/path/to/64/bit/include"]
        cpp.distributionLibraryPaths: ["C:/path/to/64/bit/lib"]
    }
...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Да, нужно будет с QBS разобраться - красивый конфиг получается!